# What means origin circuit in Tor Project?

Tags: source-code

When I read source code of Tor,I found a concept called origin circuit, which appears a lot in the source code. I think it refers to the circuit from OP to OR.Is that correct? And what are the differences among origin_circuit_t, or_circuit_t and circuit_t? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These circuit objects link connections together. An `origin_circuit_t` represents the beginning of a circuit. It links application connections (for example, SOCKS connections from a web browser) to the first relay connection (for example a connection to the guard). An `or_circuit_t` is used where most other connections need to be linked. For example at a relay which links a relay connection (from a client or relay) to a relay connection to some other relay, or a relay connection to edge connections (connections leaving the tor network).

Both `origin_circuit_t` and `or_circuit_t` contain a `circuit_t`. In an OOP sense, `origin_circuit_t` and `or_circuit_t` "inherit" from `circuit_t` and so are subtypes of `circuit_t`. You can use `TO_CIRCUIT()` to cast either to a `circuit_t`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer has helped me a lot in the understanding of Tor source code!